# create minimalistic image - exec: no such file or directory

Tags: docker

I'm learning Docker and I'm trying to create the most simple and light image as possible. That's what I did.

- `helloworld` directory:

```
$ ls
Dockerfile  helloworld.c
```

- `helloworld.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

- `Dockerfile`

```
FROM scratch
COPY helloworld /
CMD ["/helloworld"]
```

I compiled the `.c` file:

```
$ gcc -o helloworld helloworld.c 
$ ./helloworld
Hello world!
```

Then I created the image:

```
$ docker build --tag helloworld .
[+] Building 0.2s (5/5) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 93B                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 33B                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [1/1] COPY helloworld /                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:c5664c4c93727aae40daca2c1fc0aa13ea2e2c58ba2962fa8d981aa0ec09012e                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/helloworld
```

Then when I run the container I get the error `exec /helloworld: no such file or directory`:

```
$ docker run helloworld
exec /helloworld: no such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I compiled the `helloworld` in a different mode?

Comment: `gcc` by default builds a dynamically linked binary, but the `scratch` image doesn't contain the dynamic loader or any shared libraries.  Build a static binary `gcc -static` or use an image that contains at least a minimum amount of shared-library infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile at docker build time, e.g.:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install gcc -y
COPY helloworld.c .
RUN gcc -o helloworld helloworld.c
ENTRYPOINT ["./helloworld"]
```

```bash
$ docker build -t helloworld .
$ docker run helloworld
Hello world!
```